# How to validate an input according to the list provided on excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of name (from A5:A36).
I want excel to validate the input on (B22) according to the list provided.
Which function should I use?

Comment: DATA VALIDATION   ,Choose List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the cells with:
Data -> Validate Data -> Select List range